# I would like to ask about simple joining technique for Django

Tags: mysql, database, django, django-models

Sorry that I am quite a newbie for Django. So, I got a trouble about simple query of joining two tables. Assuming that I have two Table call "table1" and "table2" that have one to one relation :
table1(fieldA,fieldB,fieldC)
table2(fieldA,fieldC,fieldZ)

I want to get result of query like

```
SELECT T1.fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldZ FROM table1 as T1, table2 as T2 WHERE T1.fieldA=T2.fieldA
```

How can I do this in Django?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are your models specified?

Comment: Yeah, you need to start thinking in terms of models and Django's ORM, rather than purely in DB tables -- that way you'll get a lot more out of the ORM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested code, written in an early-commute daze on the train, but this should work:

```
results = Table1Model.objects.filter(fieldA__in = Table2Model.objects.all().values_list('fieldA',flat=True))
```

This will get you queryset of the relevant Table1ModelObjects. If you want just the values, add this after the final brace, above:

```
.values_list('fieldA','fieldB','fieldC','fieldZ', flat=True)
```

Or, instead of all that, remember you can fall back to raw SQL:

```
results = Table1Model.objects.raw("SELECT T1.fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldZ 
                                   FROM table1 as T1, table2 as T2 
                                   WHERE T1.fieldA=T2.fieldA")
```

which will give you back objects, too (assuming you're using Django 1.2). If you wanted just values, add the values_list bit from above, or look at extra() in the [queryset reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the join implicitly using [`extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none):

```
Table1Model.objects.extra(
    tables=['table2'],
    where=['table1.fieldA = table2.fieldA']
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I figure it out how this work now.. many thanks again.. :)